# Webpack React download page with state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack-dev-server development for debugging my React Node application, and webpack for compile code and render page.

I have page, for example: with menu, in menu is option 'Login\Register' replaced with 'Account'. The value is switched by state in React `this.state.isLogged`. Default value `isLogged` is `false`.

When page is loading, I want to check login state on server. Now I'm doing this by ajax request, when component is mounting. After receiving ajax data, is setting state from server. But this method is long and takes a lot of time.

I'm looking for method to load state data when page (html and javascript files) are loading by the browser.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I'm write some detalis.

code of page I build on my own computer. After 3 files `index.html`, `style.css` and `main.js` are move to my server with NodeJS. I don't want to render page on server, because I haven't permission to compile files.

Comment: Use a template engine like `jade` or `handlebars` and query the data on the back-end and pass it directly in the HTML template when loading the page. In this way you'll have it the moment the front-end script executes

Comment: But how use it, when I have builded page? I use this command `webpack --mode production` and after i have 3 files: `index.html`, `main.js` and `style.css`. In `main.js` I have all body of page.

Comment: And I want before download `main.js` with all code of page, set item in menu `Account` for logged or `Login/Register`. On server I use NodeJS with express-session.